# Thread Pool and Parallel.For combination - is it possible

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In my application I have a number of classes that can compute their tasks using `Parallel.For` statement. Each `Parallel.For` uses its own `ParallelOption` that sets a maximum degree of parallelism.

The application flow is dependent on a user setup so there are situations like: class A (which computes in parallel) calls class B (that also computes in parallel) or it calls class C (that is not using any parallel computing).

Another pattern is recursive calls where on each level of recursion a parallel computation is done.

My questions:

Is it possible to setup a global thread pool that is used by all classes to do its calculatins, and the numer of threads is controlled globally for application?

Is it possible to combine thread pool with `Parallel.For` so most of the existing code stays unchanged?

How much overhead puts a thread pool compared to independend parallel.for calls (I know that it all depends, ad by the end I need to do some testing, but maybe you have some good and bad expirence and good advices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to setup a global thread pool that is used by all
>   classes to do its calculatins, and the numer of threads is controlled
>   globally for application?

This is already the case. Currently, the application thread pool is managed by the .NET runtime. So you can be pretty sure, that all your classes (in a running application) use the same thread pool. You can access the thread pool either by using `Task`s, the static `ThreadPool` class or the static `Parallel` class.

> Is it possible to combine thread pool with Parallel.For so most of the
>   existing code stays unchanged?

`Parallel.For` internally uses `Tasks` and the `TaskScheduler`. So, the same thread pool will be used.

Comment: Do you know how to control the size of the Thread pool? How many Threads there are if a Parallel.For is called with MAXDOP = 10 and then in each thread I call a method which calls another Parallel.For with MAXDOP = 10. Is is 10 + 10* 10 maximum?

Comment: @SebastianWidz, you shouldn't control the thread pool size, you can't do that directly. The .NET runtime almost certainly can do it more effectively. You should read more about [parallel loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx). Setting a degree of parallelism to 10 on a 2 core system will probably slow down the whole process.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that too high DOP can slow down, currently I set MAXDOP = Environment.ProcessorCount, but what happens when a single thread calls a method which call another parallel loop - you get the multiplication of the number of threads. That's why I've asked this question. Wouldn't it be convenient to set a constant number od threads for all calls together

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.For` will use all the thread pool threads by default, and the number of thread pool threads is optimized for your cpu(s). `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is only useful if you want to *not* use all of the thread pool threads for a given loop.

*Just use `Parallel.For` and don't overthink it.*

Later on, if your app really requires it, you can still create your own `TaskScheduler` with your own thread pool... but it's very improbable that you actually need to do that.